# Glare effect in compositing on one object in Blender 2.8

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: Glare node]I want to add a glare effect in compositing on exactly one object in blender 2.8, so what's the way of doing it?
What I want is to lock this glare node only on one object in scene, not the whole scene.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Would you mind sharing what you already tried, and why it didn't work for you? You can also upload some images, for people with bad imagination (like me).

Comment: Start by re-arranging the nodes a bit. Put the 'image' output from the Denoise node into the 'image' input of the Glare node. Then feed the Glare node's output into the Composite node. You will have to uncheck 'use alpha' for the glare to work.

Comment: Depending of EEVEE or Cycles render, you can try cryptomomath to pick specitif element, and use it as mask in the factor of the mix node.

Answer (score -2):

If I were you, I would find a way to render just the object you want to have glare on. I learned something like this was possible from InLightVFX's videos. Then, you could render the rest of the scene and composite the two renders on top of each other.

Comment: Could you please add more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)